# The sum of the products of a two-dimensional array python

Tags: python, arrays, math

I have 2 arrays of a million elements (created from an image with the brightness of each pixel)
I need to get a number that is the sum of the products of the array elements of the same name. That is, A(1,1) * B(1,1) + A(1,2) * B(1,2)...
In the loop, python takes the value of the last variable from the loop (j1) and starts running through it, then adds 1 to the penultimate variable and runs through the last one again, and so on. How can I make it count elements of the same name?
res1, res2 - arrays (specifically - numpy.ndarray)
Perhaps there is a ready-made function for this, but I need to make it as open as possible, without a ready-made one.

```
sum = 0
for i in range(len(res1)):
    for j in range(len(res2[i])):
        for i1 in range(len(res2)):
                for j1 in range(len(res1[i1])):
                    sum += res1[i][j]*res2[i1][j1]
```

Comment: `(res1 * res2).sum()`?

Comment: It's a little different. It seems to me that the value is less. And in any case, I can't use ready-made functions in this case. But thanks.

Comment: Do not use `sum` as the name of a variable in python. `sum` is the name of a builtin function in python. Shadowing builtins is confusing and can have unexpected consequences, because of the way variable names are scoped in python. Here is the list of builtins: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html Do not use those names for your own variables.

Comment: Just use two loops instead of four loops: `s = 0; for i in range(len(res1)): for j in range(len(res1[i])): s += res1[i][j] * res2[i][j]`

Comment: Or alternatively, using builtin function `sum`: `s = sum(res[i][j] * res2[i][j] for i in range(len(res1)) for j in range(len(res1[i])))`

Comment: But if you are really dealing with arrays of millions of elements, you should really use `numpy` arrays rather than python arrays. numpy is a reaaaaaally good library to manipulate big arrays of numbers. There is no excuse not to use it.

Comment: Or alternatively using `zip` to iterate on the two arrays at once while avoiding using clunky `range(len(res1))`: `s = sum(x * y for row1, row2 in zip(res1, res2) for x, y in zip(row1, row2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part of my answer I'll explain how to fix your code directly. Your code is almost correct but contains one big mistake in logic. In the second part of my answer I'll explain how to solve your problem using `numpy`. `numpy` is ***the*** standard python package to deal with arrays of numbers. If you're manipulating big arrays of numbers, there is no excuse not to use numpy.

### Fixing your code

Your code uses 4 nested `for`-loops, with indices `i` and `j` to iterate on the first array, and indices `i1` and `j1` to iterate on the second array.

Thus you're multiplying every element res1[i][j] from the first array, with every element res2[i1][j1] from the second array. This is not what you want. You only want to multiply every element `res1[i][j]` from the first array with the corresponding element `res2[i][j]` from the second array: you should use the same indices for the first and the second array. Thus there should only be two nested `for`-loops.

```py
s = 0
for i in range(len(res1)):
    for j in range(len(res1[i])):
        s += res1[i][j] * res2[i][j]
```

Note that I called the variable `s` instead of `sum`. This is because `sum` is the name of a builtin function in python. Shadowing the name of a builtin is heavily discouraged. Here is the list of builtins: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html ; do not name a variable with a name from that list.

Now, in general, in python, we dislike using `range(len(...))` in a for-loop. If you read [the official tutorial and its section on `for` loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), it suggests that `for`-loop can be used to iterate on elements directly, rather than on indices.

For instance, here is how to iterate on one array, to sum the elements on an array, without using `range(len(...))` and without using indices:

```py
# sum the elements in an array
s = 0
for row in res1:
    for x in row:
        s += x
```

Here `row` is a whole row, and `x` is an element. We don't refer to indices at all.

Useful tools for `looping` are the builtin functions `zip` and `enumerate`:

- `enumerate` can be used if you need access both to the elements, and to their indices;
- `zip` can be used to iterate on two arrays simultaneously.

I won't show an example with `enumerate`, but `zip` is exactly what you need since you want to iterate on two arrays:

```py
s = 0
for row1, row2 in zip(res1, res2):
    for x, y in zip(row1, row2):
        s += x * y
```

You can also use builtin function `sum` to write this all without `+=` and without the initial `= 0`:

```py
s = sum(x * y for row1,row2 in zip(res1, res2) for x,y in zip(row1, row2))
```

### Using `numpy`

As I mentioned in the introduction, `numpy` is a standard python package to deal with arrays of numbers. In general, operations on arrays using numpy is much, much faster than loops on arrays in core python. Plus, code using numpy is usually easier to read than code using core python only, because there are a lot of useful functions and convenient notations. For instance, here is a simple way to achieve what you want:

```py
import numpy as np

# convert to numpy arrays
res1 = np.array(res1)
res2 = np.array(res2)

# multiply elements with corresponding elements, then sum
s = (res1 * res2).sum()
```

Relevant documentation:

- [sum: `.sum()` or `np.sum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html#numpy.ndarray.sum);
- [pointwise multiplication: `np.multiply()` or `*`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html);
- [dot product: `np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Comment: I did as you wrote. But when checking (I added print(S) itself to the loop after s += x * y), it outputs not what is needed at all.
The elements of the array are mostly greater than 100 (the picture is light). For example
res1(1,1) = 130, res1(1,2) = 130, res1(2,1) = 130, res1(2,2) = 130;
res2(1,1) = 129, res2(1,2) = 137, res2(2,1) = 129, res2(2,2) = 137;
That is, when multiplying, a large number should come out. And in the end it comes out:
130
276
350
486
706
907
1000
1240

Comment: And when I use the first method, after completing the check, 50 is printed from somewhere, then 100, 132, 164, etc. Although I repeat that my array mostly contains elements greater than 100.
I want to understand why arrays don't work, and if the end result can be trusted.
Perhaps python doesn't like it when print(s) is wedged into the loop, it worked in pascal, but...

Comment: Also, a RuntimeWarning error appears: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
  s += res1[i][j] * res2[i][j], but I read that it's just a warning and everything works fine in the end. But suddenly..

Comment: I added a check to the loop, and here's the result...
print(x) #89
print(y) #130
print(x*y) #50
How can it be....In this regard, the whole calculation goes wrong

Comment: @Alex Presumably the "byte" in "ubyte_scalars" means your integers are stored not as standard python integers, but as bytes. A byte can take only 256 distinct values. Thus presumably all your arithmetic is done modulo 256. And indeed `(89 * 130) % 256 == 50`. I don't know why you're using bytes rather than usual integers. You can do `s += int(x) * int(y)` to force the conversion to integers.

Comment: @Alex: Did you try the numpy solution? Do you have the same ubyte issue with numpy? I think there shouldn't be any issue, but if there is, you can replace `res1 = np.array(res1)` with `res1 = np.array(res1, dtype=np.uint)` or even `res1 = np.array(res1, dtype=np.ulonglong)` to fix it.

Comment: With `dtype=np.uint`, the number is significantly smaller, which is obviously wrong. But with `dtype=np.ulonglong`, everything looks quite realistic. The values ​​are the same as in the loop. Thank you very much!
For some reason, I thought that python and numpy in particular would work with integers at once, and I would not need to convert the data ...

Comment: @Alex Python integers are unbounded. Numpy integers are bounded, but usually by a fairly large number such as 4294967296. However, it appears that your array used `ubyte_scalars` for some reason. I don't know why - I've never had this issue myself. I assume the python module that you used to create your array uses a different type of numbers internally.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
import numpy as np

a,b = np.array(range(100)), np.array(range(100))

print((a * b).sum())
```

Solution 2 (more open, because of use of pd.DataFrame):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a,b = np.array(range(100)), np.array(range(100))

df = pd.DataFrame(dict({'col1': a, 'col2': b}))

df['vect_product'] = df.col1 * df.col2

print(df['vect_product'].sum())
```

Comment: I really don't understand how pandas dataframe are relevant here? They will just make everything slower for no reason. I don't know what you mean by "more open". Numpy is the appropriate tool for this problem, and pandas seems to add clunkyness unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Also, `np.arange(100)` is more efficient than `np.array(range(100))` (and easier to read, because it has fewer parentheses).

Comment: Also, in this case, `a @ b` and `np.dot(a, b)` give the same result as `(a * b).sum()`

Comment: Also, the OP is talking about 2d arrays, but your answer has 1d arrays.

Comment: @Stef, You are right about np.dot() and pandas, but reread author question, please. He said directly, that he doesn't looking for 'ready-made' functions and looking for some 'open solution' that I understood as 'something easy to work with for new ones'. That's it.

Comment: I did read the question, yes. I don't understand your point. I have no idea what you mean by "pandas is more open". (1) Numpy is the best tool for the job, and by far. I see absolutely no argument in favour of pandas. (2) The mistake in the OP's code is that they use 4 nested for-loops instead of just 2, so they're using different indices to iterate on the two arrays, instead of the same indices.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple and fast options using numpy are: `(A*B).sum()` and `np.dot(A.ravel(),B.ravel())`. The first method sums all elements of the element-wise multiplication of `A` and `B`. `np.sum()` defaults to `sum(axis=None)`, so we will get a single number. In the second method, you create a 1D view into the two matrices and then apply the dot-product method to get a single number.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
B = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

s = (A*B).sum()  # method 1
s = np.dot(A.ravel(),B.ravel())  # method 2
```

The second method should be extremely fast, as it doesn't create new copies of `A` and `B` but a view into them, so no extra memory allocations.

Comment: Why do you call `.sum()` twice? It doesn't matter the dimension of an array `C`, `C.sum()` is already the sum of all elements in `C`. To sum along one axis only you need to specify the axis: `C.sum(axis=0)` or `C.sum(axis=1)` or `C.sum(axis=-1)`, etc